# SevenZipSharp, how to read txt file?

Tags: c#, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I am trying to read txt files from .7z archive

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(f + "//" + file.FileName))
```

but I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\1.7z\1\2\3\New Text Document.txt'.

```
if (IntPtr.Size == 8) //x64
            {
                SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll");
            }
            else //x86
            {
                SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.dll");
            }

            string f = "E://1.7z";
            SevenZipExtractor extractor = new SevenZipExtractor(f);

            foreach (ArchiveFileInfo file in extractor.ArchiveFileData)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} Bytes", file.FileName, file.Size);

                if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(f + "//" + file.FileName))
                    {
                        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} ", reader.ReadLine());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: you are using incorrect path

Comment: `f` points to a file, not a folder. You can't treat a zipped file as if it were a folder

Comment: You are using the SevenZipExtractor only to read the file name, not to extract anything. I'm not familiar with the library, but that seems wrong.

Comment: using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\" + file.FileName)) use this

Answer (score 1):

To use SevenZipExtractor to extract a file, use the following:

```
String file = @"\\yourdirectory\\yourzipfile.zip";  
String directoryToExtract = @"\\yourdirectorytoextract"
using (SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor extr = new SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(file))
{
             Console.WriteLine("Extracting File...");
             extr.ExtractArchive(directoryToExtract);
             System.IO.File.Delete(file);   
}
```